# How to export/ save the model with Mix Shader material?

Tags: export

I am building a Blender Add-on and want to generate and export materail with Mix shader. However, Mix Shader is only avaliable for blender. So, I can not export the model as **.obj** or **.glb**.

Does anyone know how to export it? Or is there any possibility to 'convert' the result of *Mix Shader* to *Texture* or *PrincipleBSDF*?

Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Than you so much!